# Why `await` a function is not an error in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

It's useless to await a function, which does not even invoke it. But it would not generate a compile time error or runtime error. I can't figure out in what cases anyone would await a function.
In the following code, `foo` will not be executed. Why doesn't Typescript ban it?

```
async function foo(){
    console.log("foo");
}
async function bar(){
    //correct usage should be:   await foo();
    await foo;
}
bar();


//generated es6 code.
function foo() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    });
}
function bar() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        yield foo;
    });
}
bar();
```

Comment: async await pattern will help you avoid using promises, you can await on function which does come time consuming tasks... Its based on C# async await pattern

Comment: I know. But I don't understand why anyone would await a function object rather than the promise it returns. @MithunPattankar

Comment: Oops sorry, my bad it allows async await uses promises internally.. TypeScript’s async/await pattern makes use of Promises, much like C#’s async/await pattern leverages Tasks

Comment: TypeScript is merely not a replacement of JavaScript, it helps code just like programming languages like C#, Java

Comment: Well, I'm asking why both expressions are legal in Typescript: 1. `await foo`; 2. `await foo()`. Apparently, the first one has no effect and is likely caused by typo. @MithunPattankar

Comment: it could be because it's easier for the compiler not to check if the received object is promise like. I'm not sure this is the right forum to answer this, the typescript github page would be better. Fill in a bug report/enhancement issue maybe? On SO @RyanCavanaugh might see your question and have a better answer. :)

Comment: You can also check the language specification for async functions in TypeScript here. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1664

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `await <expression>` expects `<expression>` to be a Promise. If it is not a Promise (by promise definition) then the value will be wrapped into a Promise. You can investigate the async-await example for `ping` from [msdn.blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/03/what-about-asyncawait/)

Formally you can expect `await 10;` to be correct. Because you can't forbid wrapping plain objects or primitive values into Promises. Thus `await foo;` works as a wrapper for plain object value `foo` (functions in [javascript are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), you know that, right?)

**Where would you use that?**

Imagine a situation when you don't know beforehand whether operation will take time. For example, you have a cache implementation.

If the object is there in memory you don't have to read it from the source (db or web) which would be an asynchronous operation. So it is resolved synchronously (read from memory). However the interface should be the same. So you will `await` a plain object.